# Convert a Ngspice rawfile to binary format

Tags: binary, ngspice, ascii

I have these NgSpice rawfiles that are generated in ASCII format instead of binary format.
I would like to know please what command to use to force their generation in binary instead or ASCII format when running the NgSpice simulation in batch mode? If no such thing exists it there a command that converts ASCII files to binary ones?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For your last question, all I had to do was open up the manual and search for `batch`. The first match was the answer. It's the same in this case. Are you really going to wait hours, or days for a handed answer instead of trying it out yourself?

Comment: @BrianDrummond No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to use in the control environment of your netlist is the following:

`set filetype = binary` (or ascii)

The `NgSpice` output rawfile is generated in binary format.

The command is to be inserted right before the `write` command if inserted. Here is a minimal working example of the `.control` environment:

```
.control
run
set filetype=binary
write path_to_where_you_want_your_rawfile_to_be_saved all
.endc
.end
```